# Trying to bake a scene with multiple objects & unique UVs into one object with 1 UV

Tags: materials, uv, texture-baking

I'm having issues with trying to bake a scene I made.
[image]

I have many objects, a bunch of them with their own UV maps and textures, and I'd like to join them all together into one object with one UV map and one texture so that I can bake it as one. Things I've tried:

-Joining all objects together, then trying every type of UV unwrap--this ends up with all the UV maps overlaying each other and textures becoming misaligned and messed up.

-Duplicating all objects, joining the duplicates together, and trying to bake the textures of the originals into a new image on the duplicates. This ends up taking forever, with things ending up mostly black and still odd-looking.

-Baking everything separately then joining them... again, textures become messed up.

-Using the Texture Atlas addon, but that doesn't seem to work either following various guides I've found on YouTube and other forums.

I've watched a bunch of YouTube tutorials and have tried following along with answers I've found in this forum, but with no success. Could anyone offer me some advice?

Here's the file if you'd like to take a peek: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2qBRR30UYv5UW90cGpVbmktaGc

Thanks in advance for any help anyone could offer! I really am enjoying learning Blender, but this has been a big roadblock.

Comment: did you try to add an additional UV Map to bake with